# How and When the Handshake Protocol to use to the Certificate private key?

Tags: encryption, openssl, certificate, tls1.3

How does the server using the Certificate Private Key to create Certificate Verify message in TLS 1.3? And how the Client using the Certificate public key to verify the handshake not to be modify? Just in TLS 1.3 not TLS 1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a good overview of the phases of the TLS 1.3 handshake I like to use this [site](https://tls13.ulfheim.net/), which breaks down the connection to easier to understand phases then going through the RFC's.

From the above site:

> Signature
>
> Because the server is generating ephemeral keys for each
>   session (optional in TLS 1.2, mandatory in TLS 1.3) the session is not
>   inherently tied to the certificate as it was in previous versions of
>   TLS, when the certificate's public/private key were used for key
>   exchange.
>
> To prove that the server owns the server certificate (giving the
>   certificate validity in this TLS session), it signs a hash of the
>   handshake messages using the certificate's private key. The signature
>   can be proven valid by the client by using the certificate's public
>   key.  08 04 - reserved value for RSA-PSS-RSAE-SHA256 signature  01 00
>   - 0x100 (256) bytes of signature data follows  17 fe b5 ... 36 9f 9e - a signature over this handshake's hash  We can verify the signature
>   ourselves using the server's certificate at the command line:
>
> #### build the data that was signed:
>
> #### 1. add 64 space characters

```
$ echo -n '                                ' > /tmp/tosign 
$ echo -n '                                ' >> /tmp/tosign
```

> #### 2. add this fixed string

```
$ echo -n 'TLS 1.3, server CertificateVerify' >> /tmp/tosign
```

> #### 3. add a single null character

```
$ echo -en '\0' >> /tmp/tosign
```

> #### 4. add hash of handshake to this point

```
$ handshake_hash=3e66361ada42c7cb97f9a62b00cae1d8b584174c745f9a338cf9f7cdd51d15f8 
$ echo $handshake_hash | xxd -r -p >> /tmp/tosign
```

> #### copy the signature that we want to verify

```
$ echo "17 fe b5 33 ca 6d 00 7d 00 58 25 79 68 42 4b bc 3a a6 90
  9e 9d 49 55 75 76 a5 20 e0 4a 5e f0 5f 0e 86 d2 4f f4 3f 8e b8 61
  ee f5 95 22 8d 70 32 aa 36 0f 71 4e 66 74 13 92 6e f4 f8 b5 80 3b
  69 e3 55 19 e3 b2 3f 43 73 df ac 67 87 06 6d cb 47 56 b5 45 60 e0
  88 6e 9b 96 2c 4a d2 8d ab 26 ba d1 ab c2 59 16 b0 9a f2 86 53 7f
  68 4f 80 8a ef ee 73 04 6c b7 df 0a 84 fb b5 96 7a ca 13 1f 4b 1c
  f3 89 79 94 03 a3 0c 02 d2 9c bd ad b7 25 12 db 9c ec 2e 5e 1d 00
  e5 0c af cf 6f 21 09 1e bc 4f 25 3c 5e ab 01 a6 79 ba ea be ed b9
  c9 61 8f 66 00 6b 82 44 d6 62 2a aa 56 88 7c cf c6 6a 0f 38 51 df
  a1 3a 78 cf f7 99 1e 03 cb 2c 3a 0e d8 7d 73 67 36 2e b7 80 5b 00
  b2 52 4f f2 98 a4 da 48 7c ac de af 8a 23 36 c5 63 1b 3e fa 93 5b
  b4 11 e7 53 ca 13 b0 15 fe c7 e4 a7 30 f1 36 9f 9e" | xxd -r -p > /tmp/sig
```

> #### extract the public key from the certificate

```
$ openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in server.crt > server.pub
```

> #### verify the signature

```
$ cat /tmp/tosign | openssl dgst -verify server.pub -sha256 \
     -sigopt rsa_padding_mode:pss -sigopt rsa_pss_saltlen:-1 -signature /tmp/sig

 Verified OK
```

Comment: Thanks. It is cleanly